# How to start worker correctly

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I have some problems with starting my Spark cluster.

I have one master and three slaves.  I can run the following processes in the image with the command `start-all.sh`, and run the master by hand with command `start-master.sh` like this:

[image]

My problem is that the worker process can't be started.

I tried the command `start-slave.sh`, and it shows this:

[image]

and the worker log file shows as the same content.

Here is the spark-env.sh:

[image: spark-env.sh]

Here are the slaves:

[image: slaves]

I really want to know why the workers can't be started and what I can do. Thanks if anybody knows.

Comment: So foolish that i am. It is solved with the command "sh start-slave.sh master-url:7077"

Comment: Post an answer I would suggest - your own.